# UTF-8 characters not stored properly to SQLite DB at runtime

Tags: java, sqlite, utf-8

I wrote following code to convert ASCII data to UTF-8.
But when I store this data to the SQLite DB. it does not store it properly.

Code to get UTF-8 string in java

```
Data = Data.replaceAll(":", "");
byte[] btarrBytes = Hex.decodeHex(Data.toCharArray());
String UTF8Data = new String(btarrBytes, "UTF-8");
```

---

### Insert query for SQLite in java

```
StringBuilder sbQuery = null;
StringBuilder sbValues = null;

sbValues.append(String.format("("
                + "\"%s\", " 
                + "\"%s\", " 
                + "\"%s\", " 
                + "\"%s\", " 
                + "\"%d\", " 
                + "\"%s\", " 
                + "\"%s\""   
                + ")",

                sID, 
                sEID, 
                sDDateTime, 
                sDevDateTime, 
                objRData.getRVersionIndex(), 
                objRData.getRVersionName(),
                objRData.getRVersionCode()
                ));

String.format("INSERT INTO \"%s\" ("
 + "\"%S\", " 
 + "\"%S\", " 
 + "\"%S\", " 
 + "\"%S\", " 
 + "\"%S\", " 
 + "\"%S\", " 
 + "\"%S\"" 
 + ") VALUES %s",
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.TBL_NAME,
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.ID.NAME,
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.E_ID.NAME,
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.D_DATETIME.NAME,
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.DEV_DATETIME.NAME,
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.ITEM_INDEX.NAME,
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.VERSION_NAME.NAME,  // This field need to save UTF-8 string
 CHSQLiteTbl.RVERSION_INFO.FLD_INFO.VERSION_CODE.NAME,
 sbValues.toString()));

return sbQuery.toString();
```

---

### Query Execution

```
Connection objConnect = null;
Statement objStmt = null;

objConnect = objDCASQLiteUtility.getSQliteConnection(sDBPath);
sQuery = objSQliteCreator.getRDataWriteQuery(.............)
objStmt = objConnect.createStatement();
objStmt.executeUpdate(sQuery);
```

Input data before conversion is

e3:83:95:e3:83:ac:e3:83:bc:e3:83:a0:e3:83:af:e3:83:bc:e3:82:af

Currently UTF-8 data are saved as follows in SQLite DB

繝輔Ξ繝ｼ繝�繝ｯ繝ｼ繧ｯ

But it should save as below

フレームワーク

Note that in debug mode data are saved properly

Also, After conversion, data is saved with proper string in MYSQL database where I am using c# for insertion. 
But data is not saved with proper string in SQLite DB from java, so I think problem is in INSERT statement at SQLite DB

As I said that at MYSQL from C# data are saved properly. there I am creating query with N as prefix before value as following => N'{5}'

```
sb.AppendLine(
                string.Format("('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', N'{5}', '{6}', '0', '{7}', '{8}', '{7}', '{8}'),"
                , ID // 0
                , DevID //1
                , sDTime // 2
                , sDevTime // 3
                , aryDcaRVerCounter[i].Index.ToString() // 4
                , aryDcaRVerCounter[i].Name // 5
                , aryDcaRVerCounter[i].Code // 6
                , sUpdateTime // 7
                , UserId // 8
                )
```

Comment: You don't need to convert ASCII to UTF-8. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How does the data look in the database?

Comment: What does `Data` (bad variable name!) contain?

Comment: How is `フレームワーク` ASCII? And are you sure that you read it correctly into your program? Because SQLite should handle UTF-8 properly.

Comment: ＠Thilo

Data is "e3:83:95:e3:83:ac:e3:83:bc:e3:83:a0:e3:83:af:e3:83:bc:e3:82:af"
it should be converted to
フレームワーク

Comment: @Thilo When I run source in debug mode, it saves properly as フレームワーク

Comment: How do you save your data (you haven't shown how you build sbValues), how do you retrieve the data, how do you print the data that you retrieved?

Comment: `btarrBytes` ends up containing the bytes you mentioned (e3:83:95:... which look like the proper UTF-8)?

Comment: @Thilo Sorry for little confusion here
Actually I first removed colon(:) from the string before conversion
Therefore string is "e38395e383ace383bce383a0e383afe383bce382af "

Comment: @RealSkeptic
Data contains "e38395e383ace383bce383a0e383afe383bce382af"

Comment: @Thilo
After conversion, data is saved with proper string in SQL database where I am using c#.
But data is not saved with proper string in SQLite DB, so I think problem is in INSERT at SQLite  DB.

Comment: I'd use a prepared statement if I were you. The problem is not in the conversion, and you have not given us much of a clue as to what you are doing with the values and what your statement looks like and how it runs.

Comment: @RealSkeptic
I agree with you that conversion is not a problem. And now I will mention here in detail the insert query and it's execution

Comment: Just not in the comments, please. You should [edit] the question and add all the information (including that `Data` string) to the question itself.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I will update question again. Thanks

Comment: Log the values of all characters in the `UTF8Data` string, and show them.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I updated the question. I tried to mention the all possible information.

Comment: ...Everything, except the actual database access code (connection creation, query execution, etc.). I am sorry, I am getting tired of milking information.

Comment: @RealSkeptic
Sorry for troubling. Now I have found the cause of the issue. data was properly converted. before saving to DB first it is saved to a text file for some purpose. from text file data is read again. and it is saved to DB. problem was in reading method of text file. I mean, it was not reading with UTF-8. Thanks for your support.